# Constraints for dynamic progress bar created using UIView in swift

Tags: swift, dynamic, uiview, constraints, progress-bar

I want to add constraints to the progress bar I created dynamically. I'm still new to constraints and most of my constraints were done on the view controllers themselves inside the storyboard. However, because this was created dynamically, I wasn't able to do that. Any help would be appreciated. It is a quiz game and the progress gets saved (index). There is a UILabel above and below the progress bar. Here is the code:

```
    //Array to hold progress bar contents.
    var DynamicView = [UIView]()

    //Current x value for next array element
    var currentX = Float()

override func viewDidLoad() {

 //Width of each progress element
        currentX=19.79

        //Fill current progress bar
        //Current progress
        for i in 0..<index {
            //Incorrect answer. Red color
            if (String(describing: (Questions[i].Answer)[0]) == String(describing: selectedAnswers[i])){
                drawStackedProgress(height: 20, y: 230, color: 1, index: i)
            }
                //Correct answer. Green color
            else{
                drawStackedProgress(height: 20, y: 230, color: 0, index: i)
            }
        }
        //Remaining progress bar
        for i in index..<50{
            drawStackedProgress(height: 20, y: 230, color: 2, index: i)
        }
}

    //Update progress bar
    func drawStackedProgress2(height:Float, y:Float, color: Int, index: Int){

        //Colors array
        let colors = [UIColor.red, UIColor.green, UIColor.gray]

        //Update current location on bar
        currentX+=Float(7.0842)

        //Color for that progress
        DynamicView[index].backgroundColor=colors[color]

        //Add progress to view
        self.view.addSubview(DynamicView[index])
    }

    //Create initial progress bar
    func drawStackedProgress(height:Float, y:Float, color: Int, index: Int){

        //Colors array
        let colors = [UIColor.red, UIColor.green, UIColor.gray]

        //Add progress to array
        DynamicView.append(UIView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(currentX), y: CGFloat(y), width: CGFloat(7.0842), height: CGFloat(height))))

        //Update current location on bar
        currentX+=Float(7.0842)

        //Color for that progress
        DynamicView[index].backgroundColor=colors[color]

        //Add progress to view
        self.view.addSubview(DynamicView[index])
    }
```

Comment: Something here doesn't make sense.  It's not totally clear what you're trying to do, and based on naming I can't figure out what `DynamicView` is.  Can you post the full implementation?

Comment: For each answer, it creates a seperate UIView. It was the only was to implement the different colors for the progress bar. So it is basically 50 UIViews that make up the progress bar. DynamicView is an array of type UIView. I'm not sure if this helps?

Comment: Oh, wow.  OK.  Well if you really want to implement with 50 UIView instances you can, but I'd suggest looking at `UIStackView` as a way to manage this much more easily than trying to add each as a subView while trying to calculate the position of each one.  The scope of the question seems a little too huge to try to weigh in more than that.

Comment: I was able to get a workaround for it. I adjusted the height and X location based on height of the Iphone being used.